# Can I pull Max and Min values in SQL without using group by for non aggregate values?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of user data for when they enroll in a program.  The fields include a user ID, start date, end date, entry reason, exit reason and program type.  For each year the user is enrolled in a specific program they will have an entry and exit date for that year along with an entry reason.  They only get an exit reason when they are exited from the program completely.  Here is an example of the data in the table.

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETGKT.png)
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQjn0.png)

I need to pull one line for each user that has their original start date in the program, most recent start date, and most recent end date.  I also need to pull the exit reason if one exists and entry reason associated with the most recent start date and this is what is getting me hung up.  I’m assuming the problem is related to having to group by the entry reason.  Is there any way around using an aggregate function to get the min/max dates?
  My query is:

```
Select
    Table1.userID,
    CAST(Min(table2.startdate) as date) as Originalstartdate,
    CAST(Max(table2.startdate) as date) as Maxstartdate,
    CAST(Max(table2.enddate) as date) as ExitDate,
    CASE
        WHEN table2.exitreason = NULL then ‘’
        ELSE table2.exitreason
    END as Exitcode,
    Table2.entryreason
From
    Table1 left outer join
    Table2 on Table1.userID = Table2.userID
Where
    Table1.status = ‘active’ and Table2.programID = ‘Program1’ and (Table2.exitreason <> ‘NULL’ or Table2.entryreason <> ‘NULL’)
Group By
    Table1.userID, Table2.exitreason, Table2.entryreason
```

Comment: CAST(Min(table2.startdate) as date) as Originalstartdate assumes that you can't change the start date to be earlier. This may be an oversight. You should use IS NULL and not = NULL assuming that you have ISO nulls set up. You could use a windowed function to get aggregate data if you needed to... 

Also, you need to modify your group by to remove entry reason. Instead, use MAX(entryreason)... I'll post a suggestion.

Comment: You are correct, once an originalstartdate has been entered it will not change.  Also, if I use Max(entryreason) won't that return the maximum value and not necessarily the most recent?

Comment: Hey Seth, I took a stab at it in an answer. I explained in a code comment that I didn't understand your intent, but if it's to grab the most recent entry reason then replace the logic that builds the list with something like `(select EntryReason from Table2 where Table2.userID = t1.userID AND table2.StartDate = MAX(table2.StartDate)) as EntryReason`

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I think I'm almost there, but I get an error when I try to use this code.  "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."  I haven't thought to use aggregate functions in a where clause before so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hey Seth, that was an example, you'd need to actually do `(select EntryReason from Table2 where Table2.userID = t1.userID AND table2.StartDate = (SELECT MAX(StartDate) FROM Table2 where userID = t1.userID)) as EntryReason`; you could also try `(select EntryReason from (select EntryReason, StartDate, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by userID order by StartDate DESC) as [rn] from Table2 t2self where t2self.userID = t1.userID) x where x.rn = 1) as [EntryReason]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below sample code in order to generate [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/71e6f/10).

The idea here is to utilize the userID as the anchor (you want one row per user, right?), aggregating the rest of the information but with the situation you requested.

CREATE TABLE SCRIPT:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  userID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
  name   VARCHAR(200), 
  stat   CHAR(1) NOT NULL
                 DEFAULT 'A');

CREATE TABLE table2
(
  t2ID        INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
  StartDate   DATE, 
  UserID      INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES table1(userID), 
  ProgramID   VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT 'Program1', 
  EndDate     DATE, 
  EntryReason VARCHAR(2000), 
  ExitReason  VARCHAR(2000));

INSERT INTO Table1
(name)
       SELECT *
       FROM(VALUES
       (
         'First name'),
       (
         'Second name'),
       (
         'Third name')) x("name");

INSERT INTO Table2
       SELECT *
       FROM(VALUES
       (
         '20180101', 1, 'Program1', '20181231', 11, NULL),
       (
         '20190101', 1, 'Program1', '20191231', 12, NULL),
       (
         '20200101', 1, 'Program1', NULL, 11, NULL),
       (
         '20170101', 2, 'Program1', '20171231', 11, NULL),
       (
         '20180101', 2, 'Program1', '20171231', 14, 2),
       (
         '20200101', 3, 'Program1', NULL, 11, NULL)
) x(StartDate, UserID, ProgramID, EndDate, EntryReason, ExitReason);
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT t1.userID, 
       CAST(MIN(t2.StartDate) AS DATE)
AS OriginalStartDate, -- This uses your logic to grab the earliest date
       CAST(MAX(t2.StartDate) AS DATE)
AS RecentStartDate, -- This utilizes your logic to grab the last start date
       CAST(MAX(t2.enddate) AS DATE)
AS ExitDate, 
-- This works because we know an ExitDate must be populated due to the where
-- criteria (which prevents people who haven't exited yet from showing up)
       ISNULL(MAX(t2.exitreason), '')
AS ExitCode, -- This is just a cleaner way to handle nulls. 
       STUFF(
(
  SELECT CONCAT(',', EntryReason)
  FROM Table2
  WHERE Table2.UserID=t1.UserID FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
AS EntryReasonList 
-- this solution creates a list of entry reasons; we could pick a best winner
-- (e.g. first entry code, last entry code..) but I created a list because
-- I didn't understand your intent. 
FROM Table1
AS t1
LEFT JOIN
Table2
AS t2
ON T1.userID=T2.userID
WHERE t1.stat='A' -- you would use status= 'active'
      AND t2.programID='Program1' -- same as before
      AND NOT EXISTS 
      -- a not exists clause will do what you want to filter graduates out
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM Table2
  AS t2self
  WHERE t2.userID=t2self.userID
        AND t2self.exitreason IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY t1.userID;
```